# React ARRAY Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, next.js, key, fetch-api, sanity

I have a document (Sanity Schema) called 'category' that contains an array called 'contained_sets', which references another sanity schema document called 'set'.

E.g., the category 'exhibitions' has a field where I can select other sets to reference from ('place a', 'place b', 'place c'). I have more than 1 'category' files. Here is an example of the fourth category (out of 6):
[image]

My gallery page works fine, and I can fetch the data for the 'category' type easily, but I need a page that can link to a new webpage that shows the selected category's contained sets. This is my set.js file so far, and I tried to add a key but I'm still getting the same error (the error

```
message never came up for the gallery page so no keys in there):
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { client, urlFor } from '../lib/client';
import { Header, Footer } from '../components';

const sets = () => {
   // fetches sanity data

  const [categoryData, setCategories] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    client.fetch(
        `*[_type=="category"]{
            contained_sets[]->{set_name, image{asset->{_id, url}}}
        }`)
        .then((data) => setCategories(data))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }, [] );

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <main className="main-gallery"> 
        <div className="title">
            <div className="title-line-left"></div>
            {categoryData && categoryData.map((contained_sets, index) => (
              <React.Fragment key={contained_sets.id}>
                <h2>{contained_sets.set_name}</h2>
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
            <div className="title-line-right"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="categories">
        </div>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default sets
```

EDIT: sorry, I didn't realise I included the commented out section (I'll remove it from the post now to prevent further confusion). Thanks for the tips though, I'll add a key to the list- but I'm actually getting the error for this part:

```
<div className="title">
            <div className="title-line-left"></div>
            {categoryData && categoryData.map((contained_sets, index) => (
              <React.Fragment key={contained_sets.id}>
                <h2>{contained_sets.set_name}</h2>
              </React.Fragment>
            ))}
            <div className="title-line-right"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: you didn't add key prop in the <li> element that you're returning after mapping categoryData.

Comment: You have to write something like <li key="something">...</li>

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the post itself, I've added an edit. I've been running the program with the ul part commented out, so the part that's giving me the error is where I have the React.Fragment key (the set_name doesn't show up), not the list part (though I'll be sure to add a key there when I get to that part, thank you). Do you know what I should do to fix that part?

Comment: are your sure contained_sets.id is passing a unique value everytime?.......why not write {index} instead of it

Comment: Thank you! The error message is gone now. the set name still isn't showing up however, do you know why?

Comment: You should console log the contained_sets once, it might not have the set name itself or it is set to an empty string. Try it once and you will find what to do whichever the case

Answer (score 1):

Just pass key={index} prop to your List Item

Q - But why react gave you warning ?

Ans - Now whenever your each List Item is changed it will have a unique key, so DOM can easily find your LI using that key and update it.

Ref - https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the post itself, I've added an edit. I've been running the program with the ul part commented out, so the part that's giving me the error is where I have the React.Fragment key (the set_name doesn't show up), not the list part (though I'll be sure to add a key there when I get to that part, thank you). Do you know what I should do to fix that part?

Answer (score 0):

pass the index as a key :

```
 <ul className="categories-container">
              {/* {categoryData && categoryData.map((category, index) => (
                  // <li key={index}>
                  //     <img src= alt={category.contained_sets.set_name}/>
                  // </li>
              ))} */}
            </ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the post itself, I've added an edit. I've been running the program with the ul part commented out, so the part that's giving me the error is where I have the React.Fragment key (the set_name doesn't show up), not the list part (though I'll be sure to add a key there when I get to that part, thank you). Do you know what I should do to fix that part?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is the immediate element which is getting returned inside map, should have prop "key" defined as unique value.

In your case it's `<li>` element & not the child element inside it. So try giving "key" to `<li>` element.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the post itself, I've added an edit. I've been running the program with the ul part commented out, so the part that's giving me the error is where I have the React.Fragment key (the set_name doesn't show up), not the list part (though I'll be sure to add a key there when I get to that part, thank you). Do you know what I should do to fix that part?

Comment: Do you still need help, or it's resolved now?